# How do I remove a review I've written from the Android Market app?

Tags: google-play-store, app-ratings

How do I delete a review that I have written from the Android Market?

Somewhere in Google's issue tracking software someone has raised this issue (I've lost the link, sorry), and the answer given was that there is a "remove review" menu option when viewing the app in question in the Market application. The person asking seemed satisfied, however there is no such menu option on my phone (Android 2.2).

Comment: What version of the Market do you have installed?

Comment: I tried removing the review from PC Web Browser. It has the option to edit the review but not to remove.

Comment: There's a delete option on the Play website nowadays. See my updated answer, @Sumit :-)

Comment: Google Plus also has an overview of all your ratings and the option to delete them (go to the **+1** tab in your profile to see them).

Answer (score 12):

Nowadays, there's a Delete button on the Play website:

[image: Delete button in Play website]

So, the remainder of this post is just in case things change again at some later time, especially as in November 2012 [Google has made things worse](http://techcrunch.com/2012/11/26/google-play-gets-real-reviews-will-now-be-posted-with-your-google-name-and-picture/), but also kind of solved the problem for existing reviews by removing your name:

> Google Play is now connected with Google+ to help you find reviews you trust.
>
> New reviews will be posted publicly using your Google+ name and picture. Your name on previous reviews will appear as "A Google User".

Also note that someone reported [Issue 16483: Android Market doesn't allow removing an existing application's rating and comment](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16483). Voting might help! Or maybe there's some alternative market app that interfaces with Google's store?

My findings:

- Despite what many write: clearing all text including the title does not clear the review for me; it just moved my old review to the top again, with a new date and an updated version number. In the Play app the "OK" button is disabled when clearing the title, so I guess the title text is mandatory. Indeed, just typing a title on the website does save the new review with an empty description. Still, that does show my name, rating and title.

  To edit one's own review on the website, even if it's actually shown on the main page: first click "All reviews" or go to the tab "User Reviews", then find the "Edit Review" button next to "My Review". Note that different languages might show different reviews! (I cannot find my review in the Dutch Google Play, as I entered it using an English Play app?)
- In the Play app one can swipe the stars to the left to get "unrated", but then the "OK" button is disabled.
- Uninstalling the reviewed app does not seem to remove one's review. (Which makes sense, I guess.)
- As true for new or updated reviews too: it takes quite some time for changes to propagate. Even once the new review is shown, refreshing might show the old one again. I guess there's multiple servers involved and it takes some time to synchronize. Be patient, for otherwise you might actually activate the old review again.
- Old versions of the Market app reveal an option "Remove my review" by simply pressing the hardware menu button, when viewing an app one reviewed. That [seems to have gone in 2.3.5](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-market/xhqdTEaXP2w) and I cannot find it in Play on 4.0.4 either.

  I tried with an old Android 2.1 device, with Market version "2002306". That old Market app still works just fine, but not all apps are visible on that old device, and some show "The requested item could not be found" when selecting it.

  [image]
    [image]
    [image]
    [image]

  Sniffing the network first shows some HTTPS request, probably authentication. Removing the rating gave me a POST to `android.clients.google.com`:

  ```
  POST /market/api/ApiRequest HTTP/1.1 
  version=2&request=CpQDCr[...]OTc2NTE4MzgYARQ
  ```

  This is a request like many others that people have been deciphering. Unfortunately [the unofficial Android Market API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) does not support these rating requests.
- Using "Manage apps" I removed all updates for the Play Store 3.5.19 on Android 4.0.4, getting me the version 3.4.7. No luck.
- I also tried AppBrain, hoping it would somehow interface with the Google Play Store and would then allow for changing ratings. No cigar.

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to your browser
2. Go to Google home page
3. At the top, click on `Play`
4. Go to the bottom of the screen
5. Click on `My orders and settings` (bottom left)
6. Select the app you need to remove the comment from.
   There will be an option to edit or delete the comment.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

On market application, click vote stars again, just clear your review text and save again. 
(you can clear your review but can't delete vote stars, alse you can change your vote stars if you want)

Comment: That does not work, well with the latest play store, if you un-rate the stars, the 'Ok' button gets disabled!

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of Google Play Store, v4.9.13, the original reviewer has to find the original review. This is easy, because in my experience, my review is presented at the top of the list of reviews. Click Edit button, and a dialog appears with a Delete button. Click the Delete button.

Answer (score -2):

The OK button shows up as disabled if you don't have everything filled out. Make sure you have the stars clicked and BOTH THE SUMMARY LINE, AND COMMENT SECTION filled in.

Comment: How does this remove the review?

Comment: This sounds like instructions regarding how to *post* a review, not how to *delete* one that's already been posted. It doesn't help the OP.